# pushin data to firebase using button

Tags: android

I have a simple question about firebase

I'm creating an app which adding some data to the firebase,
when the user clicks on the button, some data should be added to firebase

How can I do this by coding ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a model with (firstname,lastname,phone), and then get reference to the database as shown below.

```
MainData mainData =new MainData("ABC","XYZ","789798");
DatabaseReference mRefrence = mDatabase.child("users").getRef().push();
mRefrence.setValue(mainData);
```

By using push with a reference you can add values to the firebase database.